# Convert a Python List Stored in a Pandas Dataframe Column, to CSV List

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column that stores a list. i.e.

| State | City |
| --- | --- |
| Oregon | [u'Eugen', u'Portland'] |
| New York | [u'New Jersey', u'Buffalo'] |
| Utah | [u'Salt Lake CIty'] |
| Texas | None |

I want to convert the list of unicode values to a simple csv list.

Something like:

| State | Cities |
| --- | --- |
| Oregon | 'Eugen', 'Portland' |
| New York | 'New Jersey', 'Buffalo' |
| Utah | 'Salt Lake CIty' |

I also need to handle cases where 'Cities' is None or the list only has one item.

There are over 1700 records, so I'd like to do this in one bit of code. I've tried weird things like:

```
df['Cities'] = ','.join(str(row) for row in df['cities'])
```

but that seemed to keep appending the list to itself in long sequences and kept returning the unicode list.

Comment: Use pandas' own [`str.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Oregon', [u'Eugen', u'Portland']], ['New York', [u'New Jersey', u'Buffalo']], ['Utah', [u'Salt Lake City']],['Texas', None]]
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['States', 'Cities'])
```

this gives

```
    States      Cities
0   Oregon      [Eugen, Portland]
1   New York    [New Jersey, Buffalo]
2   Utah        [Salt Lake City]
3   Texas       None
```

then operating on a copy first get rid on the none then make the string

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1 = df1.dropna()
df1['Cities'] = df1['Cities'].apply("','".join)
df1['Cities'] = "'" + df1['Cities'] + "'"
df1
```

and this gives

```
    States      Cities
0   Oregon      'Eugen','Portland'
1   New York    'New Jersey','Buffalo'
2   Utah        'Salt Lake CIty'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

    # sample data
    df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]})

    # function to convert list to CSV format
    def list_to_csv(lst):
        return ','.join(map(str, lst))

    # apply function to column containing lists
    df['col2_csv'] = df['col2'].apply(list_to_csv)

    # display the result
    print(df)
```

Output:

col1  col2       col2_csv

0  1 [4, 5, 6]       4,5,6

1  2 [7, 8, 9]       7,8,9

2  3 [10, 11, 12]  10,11,12